# Powershell error during removal of first character from each line of a file

Tags: powershell, substring

Thanks in advance for your help. I found a way to remove the first character of each line in a file:

[image]

```
Powershell -command "get-content %INFILE% | foreach {$_.substring(1)}" > %OUTFILE%
```

I'm able to get the output file, however, i keep getting a bunch of  these errors:

[image]

Comment: Please edit this post and use regular text and markdown. Posting images of code is a bad idea for many reasons. The post is useless for people who have sight problems and are maybe accessing the site using text-to-speech software. The image is only guaranteed to be legible on YOUR monitor. Anyone with a different monitor (e.g. different DPI, higher resolution, viewing on a tablet etc) will be unable to read the tiny little fonts.
Image questions are often ignored.

Comment: Thank you, will try not to use image in future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you have blank lines in the input file (possibly even a trailing LF). In this case line length will be zero (as `Get-Content` strips CRLF from each line), so start index 1 for `String.Substring()` will be invalid, exactly as the error message says.

Possible fix:

```sh
Powershell -command "get-content %INFILE% | foreach {$_.Substring([Math]::Min(1, $_.Length))}" > %OUTFILE%
```

I'm using function `Math.Min()` to ensure the start index won't be greater than the line length.